# Rails - enum not included in the list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I have this enum in my rb file.

```
enum :var, %i[LOL], default: nil
```

I want to be able to properly save this object when var is nil.
However, instead I get the error "not included in the list". Is there a way how I can avoid this error?

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid ``enum`` definition to me. Enums take an array of symbols rather than a single symbol (so something like ``%i[foo bar]``). Prior to 6.1 there isn't a way to set a default other than at the database level. In 6.1 you can set the default, but I think the option is ``_default`` -- could be wrong about that as I haven't used 6.1 yet.

Comment: What's your Rails version?

Comment: Rails Version: 4.2.8